# NSURLSessionconfiguration.shouldUseExtendedBackgroundIdleMode : what does it do?

Tags: ios, nsurlsessionconfiguration

Could not find any documentation on this instance variable.

Is it related at all to being able to handle the response to a network request even when the app has been moved to the background?

Answer (score 2):

From the SDK's NSURLSession class comments:

### "Enable extended background idle mode for any tcp sockets created. Enabling this mode asks the system to keep the socket open and delay reclaiming it when the process moves to the background."

So, it looks like this is aimed at prolonging a network connection that is active when the user sends the app from the foreground to the background and it enters suspended state.